# Dynamic Columns Based on the year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my query

```
select top 10 
    Cardname, sum(T1.LineTotal) as 'sales' 
from 
    OINV T0 
inner join 
    Inv1 T1 on T0.Docentry = T1.DocEntry  
where 
    year(T0.docdate) = 2021 
group by 
    T0.Cardname 
order by 
    sum(T1.LineTotal) desc
```

But I need the output like below for the three span. if year is 2021
the response will be top customers in 2021 AND include year 2020 and 2019 for those customer. The columns must be dynamic

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @larnu so alias name should not use as t1,t2,t3 is it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation

```sql
select top 10
  o.Cardname,
  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(o.docdate) = 2021 THEN oi.LineTotal END) as [2021_Sales],
  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(o.docdate) = 2020 THEN oi.LineTotal END) as [2020_Sales], 
  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(o.docdate) = 2019 THEN oi.LineTotal END) as [2019_Sales],
  SUM(oi.LineTotal) as [Total]
from OINV o
inner Join Inv1 oi on o.Docentry = oi.DocEntry
group by o.Cardname
order by SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(o.docdate) = 2021 THEN oi.LineTotal END) desc;
```

If you need dynamic column names (I'd advise you not to if at all possible), you can build the query dynamically and use `sp_executesql`.

Note that normally you should use `QUOTENAME` on values injected into the SQL. I have not done this here because they are all `int`.

If you have any other variables that need to be passed in, do not inject them, just pass them as regular parameters to `sp_executesql`

```sql
DECLARE @startYear int = 2021;

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = CONCAT('
select top 10
  o.Cardname,
  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(o.docdate) = ', @startYear, ' THEN oi.LineTotal END) as [', @startYear, '_Sales],
  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(o.docdate) = ', @startYear - 1, ' THEN oi.LineTotal END) as [', @startYear - 1, '_Sales], 
  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(o.docdate) = ', @startYear - 2, ' THEN oi.LineTotal END) as [', @startYear - 2, '_Sales],
  SUM(oi.LineTotal) as [Total]
from OINV o
inner Join Inv1 oi on o.Docentry = oi.DocEntry
group by o.Cardname
order by SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(o.docdate) = ', @startYear, ' THEN oi.LineTotal END) desc;
');

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: can show me how

Comment: @Cahrlie  the query is static, if they pass the value as 2020.. the column values must change

Comment: OK done that now

Comment: When i execute i getting an error

Comment: Fixed a few typos now

Comment: I would personally not use dynamic SQL and give the columns static names, such as "YearSelected", "YearPrior" and "Year2Prior" and if the column names *"really"* need to be dynamic they can easily be aliased in the presentation layer.

Comment: @Larnu I agree 100%, and I did say *I'd advise you not to if at all possible*

Comment: Yes, I was just giving the OP an alternative to hard coded, and potentially incorrect, column aliases.

Comment: @larnu can you help me to write the query for my reference based on the year parameter as per your advice static columns

Comment: That answer is already in the above by Charlieface, @VignaHariKarthik ...

Comment: @laru how do it do it for three years.

Comment: Just use the first query I gave, replace `2021` with a variable `@startYear` and `2020` with `@startYear - 1` etc

Comment: can send me another query with out the dynamic sql if possible.. just for my reference. Because the query needs to defined in the api.  That's why need to test whether can change the response dynamically or not.